# If Validator Fails, dont return Back - Laravel

Tags: laravel

If I click on a button, a form displays (display flex) from include file.

```html
$('.show-restaurant').click(function(){
    openModal($('.visit-restaurant'));
});
```

What do I need to type into my 'validator fails section' for the form not to return back, but stays as 'display flex' and return the errors? Im using Laravel 7.

```html
        $inputs = request()->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($inputs, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',    
            'number' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required',
            
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return back()
                        ->withErrors($validator);
        }

        $data = array(
            'name' => request()->name,
            'surname' => request()->surname,
            'email' => request()->email,
            'number' => request()->number,
            'date' => request()->date,
            'more_details' => request()->more_details,
        );
```

Comment: why aren't you using HTML Input validation for such validations?

Comment: @VPC any client side validation rules (HTML, JS) can be removed easily

Comment: once you get your errors in json format you can either use jquery or any other frontend framework to show errors

Answer (score 0):

You can return it in form of json or even if the request is ajax laravel automatically sends json response.
To send error messages as json,

```
if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
        }
```